# Difference between Keys.Shift and Keys.ShiftKey

Tags: c#, .net, key, modifiers

In my application i detect when a key is pressed and see if the modifier is the shift key but the Keys enumerator has Shift and ShiftKey.

It seems the event is always sending Keys.Shift, but is there a case where the Keys.ShiftKey will be used?

(and the same question applies to Keys.Control and Keys.ControlKey)

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Keys.Shift` is a modifier key (used for key combinations) while `Keys.ShiftKey` is a regular key code just like most others in the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enumeration.

Comment: Does this mean that Keys.Shift could be triggered from a special mouse or some other peripheral, while Keys.ShiftKey cannot?

Comment: That makes alot of sense. Thanks for your help. p.s. is there a reason they could have the same enumerator value for both?

Comment: @Brian @Ryan If you look at [`KeyEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx), you'll use `Keys.Shift` to check against `KeyEventArgs.Modifiers` while you would use `Keys.ShiftKey` to check against `KeyEventArgd.KeyCode`. Check out the examples in MSDN.

Comment: You'd also use `Keys.Shift` when checking against `Control.ModifierKeys`

Answer (score 9):

`Keys.ShiftKey` refers to the actual shift key while `Keys.Shift` refers to the shift modification itself. `Keys.ShiftKey` can be used like the other key codes to check for presses, but you cannot check to see if the `Keys.Shift` was pressed because it represents a state rather than an object. I hope this makes sense.

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx