# C# Cannot handle Ctrl+K event of textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, event-handling, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to perform some actions when the user presses `Ctrl + K` on a textbox.

```
 private void subject_TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.K)
                  MessageBox.Show("!");
        }
```

Nothing happens when I run it.

When I debug I can see that `e.Control` is true (this means I pressed Ctrl) but the `e.KeyCode` is not equivalent to K.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: @Ivar, 76 or Shift, which is definitely not right: I press Ctrl _K.

Comment: @user3165438:- Try `if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.K))`

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me. By setting a breakpoint to `MessageBox.Show("!");` `e.KeyCode` is 75.

Comment: `LButton` is your left mouse button. Are you clicking it by any chance?

Comment: @Ivar, not at all. Any ideas???

Comment: `KeyData` contains `ShiftKey`, but `Shift` is `false`. Something is strange. Could some other event handler have changed the event? Or could it have something to do with localization? Just throwing around Ideas.

Comment: @FabianH, May this is since the Ctrl is captured but the event is fired before I press K as well?

Comment: ShiftKey and Shift are not the same thing - [Difference between Keys.Shift and Keys.ShiftKey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446927/c-sharp-difference-between-keys-shift-and-keys-shiftkey)

Comment: @stuartd, Thanks. This means that the Ctrl is captured as well as the other key capture. Why the other key is recognized as shiftkey?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325430/control-keydown-event-trap-ctrl-c-etc)

Comment: BTW...don't trust the visualizer for key press data...it lies to you because it's an interpretation of flags and not fixed values.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really don't know what is the problem reason.
May the event is fired as soon as the `Ctrl` is pressed, without waiting to the `K` to be pressed as well.

However, when I use the same code in the `TextBox_KeyUp` event, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.K) && focusedTextbox == subject_TextBox)
        {
           //Some Code
        }
    }
private TextBox focusedTextbox = null;


 private void subject_TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MethodName(e.KeyCode)
        } 
 private void MethodName(Keys keys)
    {
        focusedTextbox = (TextBox)sender;
    }
```

Use this code, this should work i have tested it myself and it will work, you will want to run the 'MethodName' method in each textbox, or if you can find a better way to change the 'focusedTextBox' field then do that hope this helped.

Comment: Testing this properly on my own i have found that using KeyDown won't work because it takes one key at a time, so it will only get the first key

Comment: Thanks, This is probably the problem reason. Upvoted.

Comment: No Problem, if it is correct, tick it so when people come onto this question they will know the answer

Answer (score 0):

In the `KeyDown event`, you just ask for the 'state' of the keyboard.

You might want to check out this topic:

[Capture multiple key downs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709540/capture-multiple-key-downs-in-c-sharp)